# Lambda's "this" capture returns garbage

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, lambda, lazy-initialization

I'm implementing my own class which provides lazy initialization of its member. And I've encountered a strange behavior of capturing `this` in a lambda.

Here is an example which reproduces this error.

```
//Baz.h
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include "Lazy.hpp"

struct Foo
{
    std::string str;

    Foo() = default;
    Foo(std::string str) : str(str) {}
    Foo(Foo&& that) : str(that.str) {  }
};

class Baz
{
    std::string str;

    Lazy<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foo;

public:
    Baz() = default;
    Baz(const std::string& str) : str(str)
    {
        //lazy 'this->foo' initialization. 
        //Is capturing of 'this' valid inside ctors???.
        this->foo = { [this] { return buildFoo(); } };
    }
    Baz(Baz&& that) : foo(std::move(that.foo)), str(that.str) { }

    std::string getStr() const
    {
        return this->foo.get()->str;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> buildFoo()
    {
        //looks like 'this' points to nothing here.
        return std::make_unique<Foo>(str); //got error on this line
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ///Variant 1 (lazy Foo inside regular Baz):
    Baz baz1("123");
    auto str1 = baz1.getStr();

    ///Variant 2 (lazy Foo inside lazy Baz):
    Lazy<Baz> lazy_baz = { [](){ return Baz("123"); } };
    auto& baz2 = lazy_baz.get(); //get() method returns 'inst' member (and initialize it if it's not initialized) see below
    auto str2 = baz2.getStr();

    return 0;
}
```

**Variant 1** works well.

**Variant 2** crashes with this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x642DF4CB (msvcr120.dll) in lambda_this_capture_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00E0FFFC.

I'm using vc++120 compiler (from VS2013).

Here is my simplified `Lazy` class:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>

template<
    class T,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value &&
        std::is_default_constructible<T>::value
        >
>
class Lazy
{
    mutable std::unique_ptr<T> inst;
    std::function<T(void)> func;
    mutable std::atomic_bool initialized;
    mutable std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> mutex;

public:
    Lazy()
        : mutex(std::make_unique<std::mutex>())
        , func([]{ return T(); })
    {
        this->initialized.store(false);
    }

    Lazy(std::function<T(void)> func)
        : func(std::move(func))
        , mutex(std::make_unique<std::mutex>())
    {
        this->initialized.store(false);
    }
//... <move ctor + move operator>
    T& get() const
    {
        if (!initialized.load())
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);

            if (!initialized.load())
            {
                inst = std::make_unique<T>(func());
                initialized.store(true);
            }
        }

        return *inst;
    }
};
```

So my question is: why does this example crashe? Is it valid to capture `this` inside constructors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, it is valid to capture `this` inside a constructor. But when doing so, you have to make sure that the lambda does not outlive the object whose `this` it captured. Otherwise, that captured `this` becomes a dangling pointer.

Which is precisely what happens in your case. The `Baz` whose `this` is captured is the temporary constructed inside the `main`-scoped lambda (the one created by `return Baz("123")`. Then, when a `Baz` is created inside `Lazy<Baz>`, the `std::function` is moved from that temporary `Baz` into the `Baz` pointed to by `Lazy<Baz>::inst`, *but the captured `this` inside that moved lambda still points to the original, temporary `Baz` object.* That object then goes out of scope and **wham**, you have a dangling pointer.

A comment by [Donghui Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6826608/donghui-zhang) below (using `enable_shared_from_this` and capturing a `shared_ptr` in addition to `this`) provides for a potential solution to your problem. Your `Lazy<T>` class stores the `T` instances as owned by a `std::unique_ptr<T>`. If you change the functor signature to `std::function<std::unique_ptr<T>()>`, you will get rid of the issue, since the object created by the lazy initialiser will be the same object as the one stored in `Lazy`, and so the captured `this` will not expire prematurely.

Comment: To add to what @Angew said, I sometimes make my class derive from std::enable_shared_from_this, and let a lambda function capture both "this" and a shared_ptr created using shared_from_this(). Capturing the shared_ptr guarantees the object outlives the lambda function. Capturing "this" is then redundant, but it makes it easier for the lambda function to access member data.

Comment: @DonghuiZhang This of course requires the object to be allocated dynamically. Which would alleviate the other issues with `this` expiring, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `this` captured is a particular object.  You copy the lambda without changing the `this` that is captured.  The `this` then dangles, and your code breaks.

You could use smart pointers to manage this; but you probably instead want to rebase it.

I would modify `Lazy`.  Lazy requires a *source* as well as a `T`.

I'd make give it a signature.

```
template<
  class Sig, class=void
>
class Lazy;

template<
  class T,
  class...Sources
>
class Lazy<
  T(Sources...),
  std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_move_constructible<T>::value &&
    std::is_default_constructible<T>::value
  >
>
{
  std::function<T(Sources...)> func;
  // ...
  Lazy(std::function<T(Sources...)> func)
  // ...
  T& get(Sources...srcs) const {
  // ...
            inst = std::make_unique<T>(func(std::forward<Sources>(srcs)...));
  // ...
```

Now `Baz` has a

```
Lazy<std::unique_ptr<Foo>(Baz const*)> foo;
```

with tweaks to ctor and `getStr`:

```
Baz(const std::string& str) : str(str)
{
    this->foo = { [](Baz const* baz) { return baz->buildFoo(); } };
}

std::string getStr() const
{
    return this->foo.get(this)->str;
}
```

and in `main` we state our `Baz` comes from no source data:

```
Lazy<Baz()> lazy_baz = { []{ return Baz("123"); } };
```